# AngularJS: Display array of objects in rows

Tags: html, angularjs, row

I have a returned array of objects in AngularJS and i want to display it in two rows.
I have something like this:

```
{"name":something ,"value0":12455.847233333334, "value1": 9.887...}
```

I have tried something like this:

```
                      <div class="row">
                       <div class="col-md-6" ng-repeat = "item in items track by $index" ng-if="$index < 10">
                      {{item}}


                       </div>
                       <div class="col-md-6" ng-repeat = "item in items track by $index" ng-if="$index >= 10">
                      {{item}}
                       </div>   

                    </div>
```

But it does not have the intended outcome. I want it to be displayed like

name: something

value0: 12455.847233333334

value1: 9.887

...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate on object keys. Like this :

```
<div class="col-md-6" ng-repeat = "(key, value) in data" ng-if="$index >= 10">
        {{key}}:{{value}}
 </div>
```

Comment: it still gets displayed the whole array. Something like this 0: {"name":something ,"value0":12455.847233333334, "value1": 9.887...}

Comment: Then you are not getting object in data, you are getting an array. So you need to take care for that. If you want to display first row data of array then -> `(key, value) in data[0]` in `ng-repeat`

Comment: Welcome, If it worked then you can accept the answer :P

Answer (score 0):

you can bind the values like these

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6" ng-repeat = "item in items track by $index" ng-if="$index < 10">
       name: {{item.name}}

       value0: {{item.value0}}

       value1: {{item.value1}}

 </div>
```